# Fired for Bad Attitude

Tags: interviewing, termination

I was recently let go for having a bad attitude and receiving customer complaints.  How do I explain this in an interview and on applications?

Comment: How long were you at the job for?

Comment: Well I'd lie about it. Say that you had a personality clash with your supervisor.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Then the hiring manager will think the OP might have a personality clash with him/her.

Comment: @Eric Still seems better than "Why did you leave your last job?" "I got fired because my bad attitude caused customers to complain."

Answer (score 3):

Well, hopefully this is a learning/growth opportunity for you.  If so, you can talk about what you've done to address the situation and how the potentially negative experience has made you a better person/employee.

Answer (score 2):

> I was recently let go for having a bad attitude and receiving customer
>   complaints. How do I explain this in an interview and on applications?

You can just be honest about it if asked. Explain what happened, and how you have learned from it.

You sometimes don't have to explain much on an application. Be brief in your words. "Not a good fit for the position" is a good answer if you aren't looking for exactly the same kind of position in the future.

Depending on the kinds of jobs you are looking for, it may not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You can "hunt the good stuff"/find the silver lining in it and explain the positive changes you have made in interpersonal tact and self-control to your employers.

Some may say leave it off your resume, but honesty is typically the best policy, and if an employer can't appreciate you learning from a bad behavior (or see you as a liability) then just move on.

Hope this is an eye-opening experience, depending on your industry, country/locality and position in your industry it can easily be the beginning of a horrible reputation. Definitely want to try to get ahead of it.

Comment: Typically, you only list the details of the job on the resume: company, dates employed, roles, duties, accomplishments. Reasons for leaving are not usually listed due to making the best use of limited space. Reasons for leaving will come up in the interview, at which point, you're right, honesty is best.